# Ajax call using Button click inside form not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I try to call server using Ajax when i click a button inside a Form. But it does not use Ajax even if i use event.PreventDefault or return false.

What could be the problem. Here is my HTML and jQuery code

```
<form action="/Patient/Search" id="patient-search-form" method="post">   
<input type="text" id="PatientName" />
<button class="btn blue-button" id="search-patients" type="submit">
 <i class="icon-save icon-white"></i><span>Search</span>
</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#search-patients').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();             
            SearchPatients();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no problem in SearchPatients() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your **submit** event handler is being assigned to the button, where it should be the form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#search-patients-form').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();             
                SearchPatients();
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Or you could bind to the button click event instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#search-patients').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();             
                SearchPatients();
                return false;
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: That is a good solution. if you use a form submit, you have to use form id `patient-search-form` like this solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#search-patients').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();             
            SearchPatients();
            return false;
        });
    });
```

you gave button Id there.We need to give form id.

Comment: I cant click my form. only i can submit

Comment: ## is not id selector only single # :)